# Retornar en una tercera columna la cantidad de registros determinados con el mismo "categid"

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero obtener la cantidad total por mes y la cantidad determinado por el "categid" en una tercera columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intento con esta consulta pero no me sale la otra columna

```
SELECT Month(proyfecharegistro) as mes, count(proyecto.categid = '3') as cantidad 
FROM proyecto WHERE proyfecharegistro BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' GROUP BY mes
```

Comment: Esto es StackOverflow en español.

Comment: ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

creo que la manera mas rápida de agregar la columna que quieres,si los datos que tu consulata ya son los que deseas, es agregando el parametro que quieres a tu consulta, de esta manera:

```
SELECT Month(proyfecharegistro) as mes, 
       count(proyecto.categid = '3') as cantidad, 
       categid 
FROM proyecto 
WHERE proyfecharegistro 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
GROUP BY mes,categid
```

Comment: amigo quiero obtener en la tercera columna la cantidad por mes determinada por el catigid : Por ejemplo si catigid=3 me tendria que decir cuantos registros hay por mes.

Comment: no entiendo bien, lo que quieres es en las primeras 2 columnas de mes y cantidad ¿ya es el resultado que esperas?, y la tercer columna que quieres ¿debe traer la cantidad por mes y cat id?  es decir que quieres agregar 2 columnas mas? donde venga catigid y otra donde venga la cantidad en ese mes?